# overleaf standalone package (for multi-file projects) - subpreamble is not considered

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am building a multi-file latex project with overleaf, following [this guide](https://it.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects#The_standalone_package).
In short, I like `moderncv` title, and i want to use that together with a simple `article` to have my cover letter be consistent with my cv.

I tried setting up a main file

```
\documentclass[class=moderncv, crop=false]{standalone}
\moderncvstyle{classic}                          
\moderncvcolor{blue}                              
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{30}{29}\mdseries\upshape}

\name{Name}{Surname}
\title{Presentation Letter}                 
\address{Street n 1}{City}{Country}
\phone[mobile]{+42~(123)~456~6789}                

\email{my@email.com}                     

\photo[64pt][0pt]{picture}                     
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle


\import{sections/}{presentation}

\end{document}
```

and in `presentation.tex` there is just

```
\documentclass[class=article, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
...presentation..
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, while the `moderncv` title looks good, the imported `presentation` does not have the expected formatting (`article` + custom `parindent`, `parskip`, `baselinestretch`).
I would also like to point out that in order to compile, I had to revert the `TexLive Version` to 2016 (Overleaf V1 legacy), otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

I hope somebody can help me, or at least point me towards another direction, maybe supported by latest overleaf engine, to combine two different files with two different preambles. Thanks